# Grouping consecutive time intervals in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, intervals

I have something like this

```
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| Room | Day | StartTime | EndTime |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1    | 1   | 08:00     | 09:00   |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1    | 1   | 09:00     | 10:00   |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1    | 1   | 13:00     | 14:00   |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 2    | 2   | 07:00     | 08:00   |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
```

I want to group by room, day and time interval but only consecutive time intervals, for example:

```
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| Room | Day | StartTime | EndTime |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1    | 1   | 08:00     | 10:00   |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1    | 1   | 13:00     | 14:00   |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 2    | 2   | 07:00     | 08:00   |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
```

I have this code but I'm not satisfied because is grouping gaps too and throws the following result:

```
SELECT
sd.Cod_Room,
sd.Cod_Day,
MIN(bd.StartTime) as StartTime,
MAX(bd.EndTime) as EndTime
FROM
Schedule.ScheduleDetail AS sd
INNER JOIN Schedule.BlockDetail AS bd ON sd.Cod_BlockDetail = bd.Cod_BlockDetail
GROUP BY
sd.Room, sd.Day

+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| Room | Day | StartTime | EndTime |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1    | 1   | 08:00     | 14:00   |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 2    | 2   | 07:00     | 08:00   |
+------+-----+-----------+---------+
```

I was reading about lead() and lag() but it's taking me more time than I thought.
I appreciate your help

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: @JamieD77 I am using 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by identifying the groups that overlap and then accumulating this value to define a group.  The following assumes SQL Server 2012+:

```
with t as (
      select sd.Cod_Room, sd.Cod_Day, bd.StartTime, bd.EndTime
      from Schedule.ScheduleDetail sd INNER JOIN
           Schedule.BlockDetail bd
           ON sd.Cod_BlockDetail = bd.Cod_BlockDetail
     )
select cod_room, cod_day,
       min(startTime) as startTime, max(endTime) as endTime
from (select t.*,
             sum(IsStart) over (partition by cod_room, cod_day order by StartTime) as grp
      from (select t.*, 
                   (case when StartTime = lag(EndTime) over (partition by cod_room, cod_day order by StartTime)
                         then 0 else 1
                    end) as IsStart
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by cod_room, cod_day, grp;
```